# Images with same repository different tags

Tags: docker

Locally I have these images:

```
myrepo/imagexxx    1                   f5d32d07d008        1 weeks ago         2.44GB
myrepo/imagexxx    latest              f5d32d07d008        1 weeks ago         2.44GB
```

If you notice, same repository name, ID and size. Only the tags differ.

1st question: I am pretty sure I didn't tagged a new image using docker commit or docker build/push with tag 1. Is this some sort of default somehow?

2nd question: on docker run/create/pull, if I do not pass a specific tag, is the "latest" image being used?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1st question: I am pretty sure I didn't tagged a new image using
>   docker commit or docker build/push with tag 1. Is this some sort of
>   default somehow?

No, the default tag is `latest` when no tag is specified.

> 2nd question: on docker run/create/pull, if I do not pass a specific
>   tag, is the "latest" image being used?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then for sure I must have passed 1 somehow.
For the rest, everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

An image is identified by an image id, that's the immutable part that won't change. It points to a set of unchanging filesystem layers and some image metadata (json you see when running a `docker inspect` on the image id). The user readable names used to pull, push, and run images are references that include the registry/repository and tag. You can have multiple references pointing to the same image (as in your example above), they can change what image id they point to, and you can end up with an image id with no references pointing to it at all.

> 1st question: I am pretty sure I didn't tagged a new image using docker commit or docker build/push with tag 1. Is this some sort of default somehow?

You'd be unlikely to commit and create the same image id. Most likely you did a pull or a run (a run will implicitly perform a pull). You may have performed a build with the same Dockerfile to tag a new name where all steps in the Dockerfile were cached. And you may have performed a `docker tag` to create a new reference to an existing image.

> 2nd question: on docker run/create/pull, if I do not pass a specific tag, is the "latest" image being used?

Without specifying a tag, docker will default to `:latest`. It is best understood as "default" since it is not necessarily the most recently pushed image to that repository. This is the default tag when you perform a `docker run` and `docker pull`, however if you performed a `docker push` without a tag, it will default to pushing all tags for a repository.

You may safely remove a extra tag to an image with a `docker image rm` command. If there are multiple tags, the tag itself is deleted. If there is only a single tag, the image would also be deleted from your local docker host (not from the registry server).